# Earth Engine GEE Abnormally low NDBI values derived from Landsat 8

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, landsat, sentinel-2, band

I wanted to compare Landsat-8 NDVI and NDBI in a city using the codes below. I am using similar formulas. However, the NDBI value is abnormally low, compared to NDVI, and compared to raster calculator in ArcGIS pro. This problem was also there when I tried using Sentinel-2 Surface Reflection. Does anyone know the reason?

```
var geometry = /* color: #98ff00 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-81.790000, 30.470000],
          [-81.790000, 30.150000],
          [-81.490000, 30.150000],
          [-81.490000, 30.470000]]], null, false);

Map.setCenter(-81.60, 30.25, 15);
var Region = geometry

var landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterBounds(Region)
    .filterDate('2022-01-01', '2022-08-31')
    .mean();

var ndvi = landsat.select('SR_B5').subtract(landsat.select('SR_B4'))
            .divide(landsat.select('SR_B5').add(landsat.select('SR_B4')));
var ndbi = landsat.select('SR_B6').subtract(landsat.select('SR_B5'))
            .divide(landsat.select('SR_B6').add(landsat.select('SR_B5')));

var ndvipalette = 'FFFFFF,CE7E45,DF923D,F1B555,FCD163,99B718,74A901,66A000,529400,3E8601,207401,056201,004C00,023B01,012E01,011D01,011301';
var ndbipalette = 'FFFFFF,CE7E45,DF923D,F1B555,FCD163,99B718,74A901,66A000,529400,3E8601,207401,056201,004C00,023B01,012E01,011D01,011301';
    
Map.addLayer(ndvi.clip(Region), {min:-0.05, max:0.5, palette: ndvipalette}, 'ndvi');
Map.addLayer(ndbi.clip(Region), {min:-0.05, max:0.5, palette: ndbipalette}, 'ndbi');
```

Comment: I also tried .median(), but similar results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the [scale and offset values](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2#bands) to the bands before using them:

```
var landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterBounds(Region)
    .filterDate('2022-01-01', '2022-08-31')
    .median()
    .multiply(2.75e-05)
    .add(-0.2)
```

Note, the thermal band has different scale/offset; you can ignore that in this case because you're not using that band.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used the scale and offset values, but the result is still abnormal compared to band calculation using data from USGS.

Comment: The USGS doesn't provide median composite data, so you couldn't have compared this result directly.  If you did a similar calculation in some other system, it's impossible to help you find what you did wrong unless you post specifics about what you did and how you did it, preferably with a full reproduction.

Answer (score 0):

```
var landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterBounds(Region)
    .filterDate('2013-07-01', '2013-07-30')
    .median()
    .multiply(2.75e-05)
    .add(-0.2)

var ndbi = landsat.select('SR_B6').subtract(landsat.select('SR_B5'))
            .divide(landsat.select('SR_B6').add(landsat.select('SR_B5')));

var ndbipalette = 'FFFFFF,011D01,011301';

var ndbia=ndbi.clip(geometry);    
Map.addLayer(ndbia, {min:-0.05, max:0.5, palette: ndbipalette}, 'ndbi');

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ndbia,
  description: 'NDBI_2013',
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13,    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that that prior Landsat products published in GEE didn't require applying the offset, I could see this causing a few erroneous calculations by inexperienced - or even experienced - users. I don't see anything in the documentation calling attention to this other than the offset column in the Bands description. Additional documentation would be helpful. I spent a few hours trying to understand why old code using prior Landsat datasets was yielding low NDVI values using the new Landsat data. Had I not had the prior results with the appropriate range of NDVI values, this error could have propagated further.